# Catch custom exception in web.xml

Tags: jsp, servlets, exception, web.xml, custom-exceptions

How do I create a custom Exception and handle it in web.xml with the error-page tag direct it to a specific page.

I have tried to create a exception extends the servlet exception like this.

```
public class MyException extends ServletException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String[] errArray;

    public MyException (String[] errArray){
    this.errArray = errArray;
    }

    public String[] getErrors(){
        return errArray;
    }
}
```

Then I put this inside web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>my pach to the exception.MyException </exception-type>
    <location>/web_service_errorr.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

And I tried to throw this in the project. Then the exception still we be catch by

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/system_error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

At the beginning of the error message it is javax.servlet.ServletException, but it has something like Root cause my MyException in the message.

If am not doing it right, how should I catch a custom exception and redirect it to a jsp page?

Comment: The `<exception-type>` is in invalid syntax. But I guess that you carelessly oversimplified/obfuscated it without realizing that you're introducing a new cause of your own problem. Please copypaste **real** code without editing it. You can always rename the package to `com.example` or so, but you need to make sure that you have **actually tested** that as well.

Comment: Thank you, I just edited the `<exception-type>` when I post it here. In the project it does display a link to that class. I was just trying to hide the package names here. Is there any problem with my implementation please?